# How can I update LibreOffice to 4.0.3?

Tags: updates, libreoffice

My version of LibreOffice is 4.0.2.2. and 4.0.3 was released three days ago.

Should I add PPA in order to get updated or my Ubuntu 13.04 will update automatically after few days?

Answer (score 1):

I would wait a while before upgrading just to see if there are any issues from such an upgrade.  But to do the upgrade you would just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-0
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Before the upgrade

[image]

After the upgrade

[image]

Or you can just wait, and it will be upgraded automatically.

Comment: thanks Mitch... I understand that I can use those commands to update, but I wasn't sure if Ubuntu will do it automatically...